# Perl: really long replace/substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string variable with two elements in it, separated by a space. I am trying to do a regex replace on that variable. Problem is, the replace is REALLY long, and I have not been able to find a way to break up the regex onto several lines.

Can someone suggest a solution to break up regex statement into several lines, or an alternate means of replacement? PerlDoc failed me here. Much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $a = "alpha beta";

# Each 'ArbitraryString' is a unique string
# For example each denotes a unique fruit and vegetable types
$a=~s/^(.*) (.*)$/${1}_ArbitraryString1 ${1}_ArbitraryString2 ... ${2}_ArbitraryString50 ${2}_ArbitraryString51 ... ${2}_ArbitraryString99/;
print $a . "\n";
```

Comment: You mean the `/x` modifier to a regular expression?

Comment: @tadman `/x` only ignores whitespace on the LHS of the substitution.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot is right. Couldn't care less about LHS, I need RHS to be split.

Comment: Can you give a bit more example? I mean, this looks like a place where you could use a loop... but it depends a bit where 'arbitary string' comes from? If it's just hardcoded, then changing that into an array (or hash) seems a sensible approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is to `eval` the replacement:

```
$r='"${1}_a ${1}_b ${2}_c ${2}_d"';
s/(.*)\s(.*)$/$r/ee;
```

this gives `a_a a_b b_c b_d` for an input of `a b`.  Obviously, you can build `$r` up over several lines if you need to.

The key is the doubled `ee` option to `s///` - this means to `eval` the replacement (giving us the contents of `$r`) and then `eval` the result of that (interpolating our current values of `$1`, `$2`, ... into it).

Comment: Beautiful. I can append to `$r` using the `.=` operator, to create a string as long as I desire, and conveniently call the substitute function. Will mark as correct if you explain the details. What does the `ee` mean at the end?

Comment: Found it! From http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators `ee  Evaluate the right side as a string then eval the result.`

Answer (score 1):

Could you not do this as a loop?

```
my @arbitrary_strings = qw ( arbitrarystring1 arbitrarystring2 ); 

my ($part1, $part2) = ( $a =~ m/(.*) (.*)/ );

my $newstring;

foreach my $element ( @arbitrary_strings ) {
    $newstring .= $part1 . "_" . $element;
}
```

Something like that? I'm afraid I'm not clear on exactly how you decide which goes before which element - is it as simple as the first half get 'alpha' in front, and the second get 'beta' in front? In which case:

```
my @first_group = qw ( trout carp haddock );
my @second_group = qw ( apple pear banana ); 

my ( $part1, $part2 ) = ( $a =~ m/(.*) (.*)/ ); 

my $result;
foreach my $element ( @first_group ) { 
   $result .= $part1 . "_" . $element . " ";
}

foreach my $element ( @second_group ) { 
   $result .= $part2 . "_" . $element . " ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm interested in regex line split.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But I'm intrigued - what's behind that constraint?

Comment: I meant that each 'ArbitraryString' is a unique value. Like apple, carrot, cabbage, potato, pear, etc.

Comment: Yes,. But is there a reason it can't be a list (array) of unique values? That way you can format for readability anyway you like `qw()` can work quite well for that, but so does just y'know, not trying to embed a long pattern in a hardcoded string.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $a = "alpha beta"; my $a1 = '';my $b1 = '';
foreach (1..99)
{
    $a1 .= $_;
}
foreach (100..199)
{
    $b1 .= $_;
}
# Each 'ArbitraryString' is a unique string
# For example each denotes a unique fruit and vegetable types
$a =~ s/^(.*)\s(.*)$/$a1 $b1/;

print $a . "\n";
```

Output:

```
123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384
858687888990919293949596979899 10010110210310410510610710810911011111211311411511611711811912012112212312412512612712812913013113213313413513613713813914014114
214314414514614714814915015115215315415515615715815916016116216316416516616716816917017117217317417517617717817918018118218318418518618718818919019119219319419
5196197198199
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to generate the replacement string and evaluate it in the substitution using the `e` option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub add_suffixes {
    my ($foo, $bar) = @_;

    my @suffixes = qw(apple carrot cabbage potato pear);
    return join ' ', map { ("${foo}_${_}", "${bar}_${_}") } @suffixes;
}

my $string = 'alpha beta';
$string =~ s/^(.*) (.*)$/add_suffixes($1, $2)/e;
say $string;
```

#### Output:

```
alpha_apple beta_apple alpha_carrot beta_carrot alpha_cabbage beta_cabbage alpha_potato beta_potato alpha_pear beta_pear
```